# Android app for Scan an RF to intercept mobile phone calls

Tags: android, wireless

I was reading following article and I come up to know about RF(Radio frequency) signals are the medium of communication between connect mobile phone calls.

Idea came in my mind to have android app kind of RF scanner which secretly eavesdrop on mobile phone conversations around you.

I know i need more research but i quickly want to know if it is possible with android apps or not ?

[enter link description here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7625971_scan-rf-cell-phone-signals.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not offer APIs to do this.    They are buried in radio kernel, which comes from pphone vendor.  So answer is negative. It is possible but not with android.

PS: COTS solutions doing this are usually restricted in export and pretty expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't see why this would be impossible. The pitfall of building an app like this would be:

a. user will most likely need a rooted phone and some kind of custom radio with their kernel. This shouldn't be a huge issue though as most users looking for something like this should have the know how to root their phone.

b. you wouldn't be able to release this on the market. as soon as google caught wind of such a malicious app they would remove it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Catching the signal of other conversation is not enough, cause signal is at least encrypted!